# jenkins: promote before job ends

Tags: jenkins, promoted-builds

I'm trying to configure a job in jenkins in a way that the promotion process (Promoted builds plugin) happens in the middle of a run. The point is that there are some annoying tasks like javadocs, sonar integration,... that can be run even after the promotion process, therefore I would like to make the build, run all needed tests and then promote the build automatically. Other tasks can run after the promotion process.

Do you know how I can implement this using the Promoted builds plugin?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Promotions only run on **completed** builds. If you want to run it in the middle of the job, then it's a **build step**, not a promotion.

You can either configure build steps for your actions (same actions as promotions). You can even call other jobs, and wait for them to complete (or not wait).

Or you can configure your "after promotion" tasks as a second promotion that is executed after the first one.